# Initialize implicitly typed local variable to IList

Tags: c#, implicit-typing

I understand that `implicitly-typed local variables must be initialized`.

I know that `result` will be an `IList` so could I somehow say that var `result` will be an `IList`?

```
var result; //initialize to something 

if( x < 0)  
{  
    result = (from s in context.someEntity  
              where s.somecolumn = x  
              select new { c1 = s.c1,c2=s.c2}).ToList();  
}

if(x >= 0)  
{  
    result = (from s in context.someEntity  
              where s.someOtherColumn = x  
              select new { c1 = s.c1,c2=s.c2}).ToList();  
}

foreach(var y in result)  
{  
    //do something . UPDATE 1: Retrieve y.c1, y.c2

}
```

Answer (score 3):

No they can't be
"var can only be used when a local variable is declared and initialized in the same statement; the variable cannot be initialized to null, or to a method group or an anonymous function."

Since you're not initializing to an interface, it won't work.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you know you want it to be an `IList`, why not just declare it as an `IList`?

Using `var` for uninitialized variables is (IMO) pretty unreadable.

Comment: I typically agree with you, but I've seen some people use it so that if they change the type name (e.g. from Human to Person) they don't have to change the declaration.  Although with most refactoring tools that's pointless

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
var result = default(IList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do something with a ternary operation:

```
var list = (x < 0) ? ... : ...
```

but really, that would be pretty painful to read. With your code as posted I think I'd just stick with

```
IList result;
```

for readability.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using System.Collections.Generic in your code then the only option available is

var list = (x < 0) ? ... : ...

If you try to use IList in the above scenario you will get the error
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.IList'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

But if you are using System.Collections you can use

IList result;